# How do I stop elements in an array being replaced every input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to write code that will output something like the following for example:

```
Dog 1 Name: Neo Toys: 3
Dog 2 Name: Henry Toys: 2
```

However, I will only get the results from the last inputs. So if I were to input the data above, I get this with my code.

```
Dog 1 Name: Henry Toys: 2
```

How do I make it so that every time I put in an input, it doesn't replace the previous one?

```
var garrDog = [];

function start() {
    var valueToPush = {};
    var vName = '';
    var vToys = '';
    vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop)");
    vToys = prompt("Enter number of toys " + vName + " has (leave blank to stop)");
    valueToPush['dogName'] = vName;
    valueToPush['dogToys'] = vToys;
    while (vName.length > 0) {
        vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop)");
        if (vName.length > 0) {
            vToys = prompt("Enter number of toys " + vName + " has (leave blank to stop)");
            valueToPush['dogName'] = vName;
            valueToPush['dogToys'] = vToys;
        }
    }
    garrDog.push(valueToPush);
    listDogs();
}

function listDogs() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < garrDog.length) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += ('Dog ' + (i+1) + ' Name: ' + garrDog[i].dogName + ' No. of toys: ' + garrDog[i].dogToys + '<br />');
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only execute `push` once; it should be in the loop. Also, make sure you define a new object in each iteration, or you will mutate the same object, resulting in an array of repetitions of the same object.

Here is a corrected version of the *start* function (the rest can stay as it is):

```
function start() {
    garrDog = []; // Add this when you want to start from scratch each time
    vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop)");
    while (vName.length > 0) {
        var valueToPush = {};
        vToys = prompt("Enter number of toys " + vName + " has");
        valueToPush['dogName'] = vName;
        valueToPush['dogToys'] = vToys;
        garrDog.push(valueToPush);
        vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop)");
    }
    listDogs();
}
```

NB: I would not tell the user that they can stop by entering nothing for the secondary question. That would leave one entry incomplete. Only leave that option for the first question.

Also, consider making *garrDog* a local variable and passing it to the *listDogs* function. It depends on whether you want to maintain the list and extend it at each call of *start*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Feel a bit silly now. Will tick you when the 5 minutes is up